# multiple strings set in standardUserDefaults retrieving null for 2nd, 3rd entries?

Tags: nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults, preferences

i've set some preferences in my app as strings: @"YES" and @"OFF" for @"Active" and @"Enabled", tried to set them upon launch in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions"
```

as

```
NSDictionary *udd = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES" forKey:@"Active"];
                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"OFF" forKey:@"Enabled"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:udd];
```

but i can only see the first string returned which is the "YES" for

```
NSLog(@"%@",[udd objectForKey:@"Active"]);
```

not

```
NSLog(@"%@",[udd objectForKey:@"Enabled"]);
```

which returns a "null".

I'm a bit stuck how to add more strings to udd for my preferences? Can anybody advise?
Many thanks in advance.
Jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x = y; z; is not what you want (it doesn't set x twice, and it definitely doesn't set x to some sort of combined value). You probably to make a single dictionary and set that, rather than two dictionaries and throw the second one away.

Comment: How do I manipulate the line of code for setting the dictionary? I've tried adding Enabled after Active by using a comma separator but Xcode states I can't have more than 2 values? In that line?

Comment: You need to make a single dictionary, not two. Use +dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:, or dictionary literals ( which are @{ } ). Fundamentally though, you need to change how you think about this. Assigning more than one value to a variable at the same time just doesn't make sense, and until the way you think about the code matches what it does, you'll have a very hard time.

Comment: I know what you are explaining now I've seen dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys. And I think I now understand why it doesn't work, my two lines of code create two dictionaries. For a new starter like myself, would you continue down this route, or create a plist? Or is there any other way. What or which would be better for extending my app further down the line. Difficult for me to predict without many apps/lines of code under my belt. Thanks, Jon.

Comment: This general approach seems just fine. You're avoiding the typical new-cocoa-programmer mistake of using -set* rather than -registerDefaults:, and you can make things nice and readable using dictionary literals.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I shall try again down this new path. Jon.

Comment: If it works out, it's considered polite to accept the answer on stack overflow (also helps other people with the same issue find it)